# Make complex google map layer render faster

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I need to render a precise layer showing the US on a Google Map. However, whenever I zoom, my fps goes down significantly.

I have already tried simplifying the GeoJSON (vertex removal), but there are two issues:

1. The new layer cuts into the US (bad)
2. The frame rate is still slow (also bad)

What can I do to improve the frame rate of my overlay without sacrificing precision?

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify and specifically quantify A) the exact FPS value, as readings below 60 will have major implications for [user experience](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/#analyze_frames_per_second) and B) what is exactly causing the FPS rate to drop below the above mentioned level as to cause a warning red line in the Google DevTools. These are just broad guidelines as to what you should do to improve your FPS rate but in case you need more specific advise to optimize the loading/rendering of your application, please [send a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the issue you are having.